# Exception: Cannot increment reference count on operation GetLocalizedStringOperation

Tags: unity-game-engine, localization

I have a problem when I first open the app and it loads localization. When the scene loads for the first time, the text that has the localization does not change to the currently active language.

Error Logs:

> Exception: Cannot increment reference count on operation GetLocalizedStringOperation, Locale: Chinese (Simplified) (zh), Table: TableReference(ee0e0481-35c1-c304-3ad9-572aa17a02e3 - app), Entry: TableEntryReference(4666258525081600) because it has already been destroyed
>
> UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1[TObject].IncrementReferenceCount() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.21.17/Runtime/ResourceManager/AsyncOperations/AsyncOperationBase.cs:203)
>
> UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1[TObject].Start (UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager rm, UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationHandle dependency, DelegateList`1[T] updateCallbacks) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables @1.21.17/Runtime/ResourceManager/AsyncOperations/AsyncOperationBase.cs:528)
>
> UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.ResourceManager.StartOperation[TObject] (UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationBase`1[TObject] operation, UnityEngine.ResourceManagement.AsyncOperations.AsyncOperationHandle dependency) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.addressables@1.21.17/ Runtime/ResourceManager/ResourceManager.cs:555)
>
> Unityengine.localization.settings.localizedstringdatabase.getLocalizedstringasyncinntternal (unityengine.localization.tables.tablerencencencencencencencers, unityengine.localization.tables.tables.table. ist`1 [t] arguments, unityengine.localization.locale local, unityengine .Localization.Settings.FallbackBehavior fallbackBehavior, UnityEngine.Localization.SmartFormat.PersistentVariables.IVariableGroup localVariables, System.Boolean autoRelease) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Settings/Database/LocalizedStringDatabase.cs: 268)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.Settings.LocalizedStringDatabase.GetLocalizedStringAsync(UnityEngine.Localization.Tables.TableReference tableReference, UnityEngine.Localization.Tables.TableEntryReference tableEntryReference, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] arguments, UnityEngine.Localization.Locale locale, UnityEngine .Localization.Settings.FallbackBehavior fallbackBehavior, UnityEngine.Localization.SmartFormat.PersistentVariables.IVariableGroup localVariables) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Settings/Database/LocalizedStringDatabase.cs:258)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.LocalizedString.GetLocalizedStringAsync (System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] arguments) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Localized Reference/LocalizedString.cs:311)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.LocalizedString.GetLocalizedStringAsync() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Localized Reference/LocalizedString.cs:263)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.PropertyVariants.TrackedObjects.JsonSerializerTrackedObject.ApplyLocale (UnityEngine.Localization.Locale variantLocale, UnityEngine.Localization.Locale defaultLocale) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Property Variants/Tracked Objects/ JsonSerializerTrackedObject.cs:184)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.PropertyVariants.GameObjectLocalizer.ApplyLocaleVariant (UnityEngine.Localization.Locale locale, UnityEngine.Localization.Locale fallback) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Property Variants/GameObjectLocalizer.cs:191 )
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.PropertyVariants.GameObjectLocalizer.ApplyLocaleVariant (UnityEngine.Localization.Locale locale) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Property Variants/GameObjectLocalizer.cs:165)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.PropertyVariants.GameObjectLocalizer.SelectedLocaleChanged (UnityEngine.Localization.Locale locale) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Property Variants/GameObjectLocalizer.cs:101)
>
> UnityEngine.Localization.PropertyVariants.GameObjectLocalizer+<Start>d__8.MoveNext() (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.localization@1.4.4/Runtime/Property Variants/GameObjectLocalizer.cs:90)
>
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at <d95181a5c71a4ad88c81e8fccee6b471>:0)

all suggestions and help are greatly appreciated